# Is there a way to do a http head request and get the time without a server side language

Tags: javascript, jquery, curl

I am trying to do a http head request from the Javascript code to get the server time ...Can I do this from javascript or do I need a server side language to achieve this

Comment: You need something on the server to respond, no?  Are you hoping that servers just have handy wristwatches?

Comment: Google 'javascript get server time' It appears there is a javascript method that causes the browser to get the server time.

Comment: @Terry **which** server time? There's no such thing.

Comment: @Pointy There's no such thing as your web server having a time? Of course there is.

Comment: basically i was hoping there would be a way to do a curl head request from javascript ....

Comment: @GregPettit sure, the server has a time. Just do an HTTP "TIME" request :-) However Josh's answer is a pretty good one, assuming the server handles "HEAD" properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your server sends the `Date` header (which the RFC [says](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.18) it MUST), [sure](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/zu7ay/):

```
$.ajax('/', {
    type: 'HEAD',
    success: function(r,status,xhr) {
        alert(xhr.getResponseHeader('Date'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Or without the use of jQuery, not much more code but possibly less error handling :

```
function getServerTime() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        alert(xhttp.getResponseHeader('Date'));
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("HEAD", "/", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```